# Change magento url structure for better Google index

Tags: magento-1.9, magento2, magento-1.7, url-rewrite, canonical

I have website with url structure like below

http://example.com/appliances.html/?cat=12
http://example.com/appliances.html/?cat=12&mfg=123

Where cat id and manufacturer id are inner categories and manufacturer of root appliances category.

As when Google index it only index upto url 
http://example.com/appliances.html
And neglect other parameters after that like inner categories and manufacturer name. 
So we have decided to create url structure like

http://example.com/appliances-dishwasher-whirlpool.html
Or
http://example.com/whirlpool/appliances/dishwasher. html
Like user friendly url which not neglect by Google index and alos focus on inner categories of website.

Also we want to change its canonical urls..

Please suggest some proper way to implement this and is there any good extension available.

Comment: The built-in magento seo features is good, but not enough to cover all your needs. Mageworx SEO suite extension is good if you know how to configure it. This extension can cover all the seo-corners of your magento. But for the layered navigation (only) I'll recommend you the Amasty shopby module with the built-in seo optimization.

Answer (score 2):

You can turn on SEO friendly urls rewrite it your Magento backend

```
System -> Configuration -> Web -> Search Engines Optimization
```

also you can look at category seo

```
System -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Search Engines Optimization
```

to get more options like canonical optimisation you should invest in SEO extension
[Mageworx SEO Suite](http://www.mageworx.com/seo-suite-ultimate-magento-extension.html) - is good but there are others out there